# read the file until HttpWebResponce is avaiable

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have the following code, in NET4

```
        String ret;
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"; httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        httpWebRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {               
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
        }
        return ret;
```

works as it should no problem there. The problem is that when the code tries to read the file on the server the server hasn't still created it yet. So I was wondering if there is a good way to wait for the file to appear on the server side before the system tries to copy it.

cheers,
ES

Comment: `if there is a good way to wait for the file to appear on the server side`, it is server's job to ensure file to be created before returning the response.

Comment: Eser you are 100% correct, the server is executing an external process that is not in my control.  I think I just have to do something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed Eser's suggestion and made the necessary changes within the server. Now the server checks is the temp file is created before releasing the result to the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
 READ_AGAIN:
 using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
 {   if(response == null) 
        goto READ_AGAIN;
     using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
     response.Close();
 }
```

Comment: I really think that using goto within OO langs is really a bad idea. What you are proposing can result in an endless loop.